# Web authentication to external resources

Tags: rest, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, portal

I am in the process of creating a web portal for my users, they can currently log in and thats it. I need to connect to a REST API with oauth2 to pull through some data for them to see but I don't want my authentication credentials to be exposed.

Is the only way to achieve this to use a server side application? If so/not what strategies should I be looking at to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd party service requires an OAuth2 secret, and you need to send it over the wire somehow. If you don't want this secret exposed, you can't do it from the browser, this only leaves server-side options.

Comment: Thanks Evert, what would be your recommendation for a beginner that actually want to make something that works? Node.js?

Comment: @newprogrammer if you are familiar with javascript, then Node.js might be easier to start with. It also depends a bit on where you are hosting it. Do you have hosting somewhere? Do you want to use AWS? How you put your application online might influence the best tool for the job.

Comment: The application will probably live on the web server which will be hosted in AWS. New to javascript but eager to learn, only a few amateur projects in C/C++ and a bit of self taught web design under my belt.